# Why do I have to navigate to a generated "editor" URL twice before it redirects properly?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm currently sending an envelope on behalf of a user (let's call them *User 1*) and adding an editor role as the first recipient of that envelope (let's call them *User 2*). After the envelope is sent, I attempt to create an editor view for *User 2*.

When I create an editor view for User 2, the first time I use the URL it automatically redirects to the provided `returnUrl` instead of the editor view for that envelope.

**Why does this happen?**

If I use the exact same URL a second time, it redirects to the editor view as expected.

---

**Example Below:**

The code I am writing uses the C# API, however, for sake of simplicity, I included a simple request that replicates the exact same problem.

**Request:**

```
POST: https://demo.docusign.net/restApi/v2/accounts/AccountId/envelopes/50545884-35da-4735-b076-f07883450146/views/edit
HEADER: X-DocuSign-Authentication {"Username":"API Account", "Password":"API Password", "SendOnBehalfOf": "User 2 Email", "IntegratorKey":"Integration Key"}
Content-Type: application/json
Body: {  "returnUrl": "https://www.google.com/" }
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "url": "https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=5dd34549-b5a1-4ccf-b039-243ce06e264d&DocuEnvelope=50545884-35da-4735-b076-f07883450146&send=1"
}
```

The first time I navigate to the URL I get redirected to Google. I copy the exact same `url` again and the second time I redirect to the expected editor view for that envelope.

---

**Updated Details on Envelope Creation:**

The header used during the creation of the envelope is similar to below:

```
HEADER: X-DocuSign-Authentication {"Username":"API Account", "Password":"API Password", "SendOnBehalfOf": "User 1 Email", "IntegratorKey":"Integration Key"}
```

- Sender: **User 1 Email**
- Recipients (as described by the envelope and request):

  - Order 1 - Editor: **User 2 Email**
  - Order 2 - Needs to Sign: Real recipient
  - Order 100 - Receives Copy: CC User 1
  - Order 100 - Receives Copy: CC User 2

---

**Easy Way to Replicate Issue:**

*Login into DocuSign.*

1. Create a new envelope.
2. Add a recipient (Email: testeditor@mailinator.com) as a **Editor in Order 1.**
3. Add another recipient (Email: testsigner@mailinator.com) as a **Signer in Order 2.**
4. Upload a random document.
5. Add a single signing block to the document for Signer.
6. Send the envelope.

*Using POSTMAN*:

1. Use the following information for the request:

`POST: https://demo.docusign.net/restApi/v2/accounts/AccountId/envelopes/{envelopeIdFromStep6}/views/edit`

`HEADER: X-DocuSign-Authentication {"Username":"API Account", "Password":"API Password", "SendOnBehalfOf": "testeditor@mailinator.com", "IntegratorKey":"Integration Key"}`

`Content-Type: application/json`

`Body: {  "returnUrl": "https://www.google.com/" }`

2. The `url` is returned: `https://demo.docusign.net/Member/StartInSession.aspx?StartConsole=1&t=cda7bdd2-0ce7-4478-a659-7984bf982687&DocuEnvelope={envelopeIdFromStep6}&send=1`

Comment: After you're immediately redirected the first time, there should be an additional URL parameter that provides a reason code for the redirect. Can you try this again and share that value?

Comment: @Drew - The full return URL is: https://www.google.com/?event=Send&envelopeId=50545884-35da-4735-b076-f07883450146. The "event" is "Send."

Comment: You mention that you are sending an envelope "on behald of a user" which makes me think you're using the older SOBO functionality (Send-On-Behalf-Of), however I don't see that in your header?  Can you confirm the details again of how you are creating the envelope and exactly how many users are involved?  Maybe that's related to the issue?

Comment: @Ergin - We are using the older SOBO functionality. The SOBO is specified in the header of the creation of the envelope and the creation of the Editor View above. The creation of the envelope (outside of what is show above) is dynamic based on our own configurations, so including the exact C# code would be difficult. The above EnvelopeId isn't real, but I could provide the real one if that would help.

Comment: @Ergin - I just found an easy way to replicate the issue. See the bottom of the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having spoken with DocuSign support, it was determined that having to navigate to an editor's URL twice is a bug. We attempted to "throw away" the first use of the URL on the server side, however, it was discovered that a cookie is set on use. This made the second use of the URL on the client side unusable.

The only noted work around is to navigate to the URL via a hidden iFrame on the client side, which will fail to redirect but establish a cookie in the browser, and then immediately use the URL a second time to redirect the browser. From an end user's perspective, the functionality will work properly.

The fix for this issue is currently in the Engineering team's hands with no known date of release or fix.